# exportArchive: "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have a Flutter app for which I am trying to build an IPA with the command: `flutter build ipa`.

I have enabled Automatically Managed Signing in Signing and Capabilities and added the correct team as well.

[image]

However, the build doesn't complete successfully and returns the following error message: **exportArchive: "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature.**

How do I solve this issue? I am using XCode 14.

Comment: Instead of using the flutter build ipa command. select all devices and click product > archive. it will generate the archive file. and also check for the you bundle identifier is already registered with the appstore connect